# Get records which satisfy particular condition and exclude others

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following data with client account decision and status

```
Client  fields value 
111 Decision    accept
111 Status  deposited
112 decision    accept
113 Decision    accept
114 Decision    accept
114 Status  contract
115 Decision    Conditional Accept 
115 Status  deposited
116 Decision    Conditional Accept 
117 Decision    Conditional Accept 
118 Status  contract
118 Decision    Conditional Accept
```

I would like to get 
records whose decision is 'accept' and also with status ('deposited', 'contract')

and get the records whose decision is 'conditional accept' and also with status ('deposited', 'contract')

in two different columns.

please help in writing case statements for this.

My output should be like:
My output should be like                                                                                     Client  fields value       newcol1  newcol2
111 Decision    accept
111 Status  deposited       111
112 decision    accept
113 Decision    accept
114 Decision    accept
114 Status  contract        114
115 Decision    Conditional Accept 
115 Status  deposited               115
116 Decision    Conditional Accept 
117 Decision    Conditional Accept 
118 Status  contract                118
118 Decision    Conditional Accept

Comment: Two questions.  Does this need to be all in one query?  Two, are Decision and Status in the same Column?

Comment: @bwilliamson I think he means to aggregate over clients.  The requirement does not make much sense otherwise.

Comment: My output should be like                                                                                     Client  fields value   newcol1  newcol2
111 Decision    accept   
111 Status  deposited  111
112 decision    accept
113 Decision    accept
114 Decision    accept
114 Status  contract  114
115 Decision    Conditional Accept 
115 Status  deposited    115
116 Decision    Conditional Accept 
117 Decision    Conditional Accept 
118 Status  contract    118
118 Decision    Conditional Accept

Answer (score 1):

Using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Client
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Client
HAVING (SUM(CASE WHEN fields = 'Decision' AND value = 'accept'
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
        SUM(CASE WHEN fields = 'Status' AND value IN ('deposited', 'contract')
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0)
       OR
       (SUM(CASE WHEN fields = 'Decision' AND value = 'Conditional Accept'
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
        SUM(CASE WHEN fields = 'Status' AND value IN ('deposited', 'contract')
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0)
```